# Yii2 kartik\select2 do not show selected value in list

Tags: yii2, kartik-v

How can I set a value to a Select2-Widget which is not in dropdown list? I load values from other table - but it is possible to deactivate entries there, they are not shown in list then. The problem is, that the value, which is not in list is not shown correctly, because the list does not know the item.

Is it possible to show (and on update save) the old value, but it should not be possible to select it from list again.

Comment: If you know in advance that few entries from items need to removed then remove it before loading the items in dropdown list. You can disable option as well using JS. Add relevant code in question.

Comment: Loading the selected item even if set inactive and disabling it would be the option I tried today. Is it possible to hide the entry from the list?

Comment: @InsaneSkull the disabledEntry is not allowed to be selected when sending form, if I disable it with options-attribute in widget.

Comment: add code of what you have tried so far.